# How to add a record to a dataframe using rbind in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to add rows to a dataframe using rbind in R.  However, the dataframe is not being updated each time I attempt to add a row.  In other words, the following code results in a dataframe with 2 columns but 0 observations when it should have 2 columns with 2 observations.

```
modeldata2<-data.frame(Model=character(),Accuracy=numeric())

modelname<-"A"
accuracystr2<-2.2
rbind(modeldata2,list(modelname,accuracystr2))

modelname<-"B"
accuracystr2<-3.2
rbind(modeldata2,list(modelname,accuracystr2))
```

I am using this at the end of a loop to record values and therefore need to first initialize an empty dataframe and then add records to the dataframe at the end of each loop.  The code above is just an example that I am using to troubleshoot the problem.  I have also tried using c instead of list but the result was the same.

Comment: You have to assign the result of rbind to the dataframe variable, like this: `modeldata2 <- rbind(modeldata2,list(modelname,accuracystr2))`

Comment: Thanks, that helps but now when it should add B 3.2 to the second observation it adds NA 3.2 and gives the error "invalid factor level, NA generated"  It doesn't make sense why it works fine with A but not with B.  Do you know why it does this?

Comment: So, when you create a string column in a `data.frame`, it converts it to factor. Since, `B` was never seen before, R is rejecting it. You should use [`tibble`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/), which is a more modern implementation of dataframes. However, if you want to keep using `data.frame` in that manner, a solution is to set strings not to be converted to factors, by adding this to the top of your script: `options(stringsAsFactors = F)`.
Example: https://repl.it/repls/SoulfulNotedMicrocode